# aar build with artifactory give Android resource linking failed error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, artifactory, aar, jitpack

I've got this error after switching from Jitpack to a self-hosted JFrog artifactory in order to build some android libraries (aar).

I have a `baselib@aar` containing a custom view provided by a third-party library:

layout.xml:

```xml
<com.github.thirdparty.signature.views.CustomView
    android:id="@+id/signature_pad"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:custom_attribute="@android:color/black" /> <--
```

```
implementation 'com.github.thirdparty:signature:1.0.0'
```

When I import it to my top level library it fail to compile giving me this error `Android resource linking failed error`, with a link pointing to the layout.xml.

It's seems that the top lib can't resolve the `custom_attribute` from the `CustomView` when trying to parse the layout.xml. 
This I've temporary solved by adding `transitive = true` to my `baselib` import

```
implementation ('com.mycompany.android:baselib:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT@aar'){
   transitive = true
}
```

Now it compile. 
But then I have two libraries using this `baselib@aar` and my final app using those two libraries which give me new error:

```
Error: Program type already present
```

The only solution that I found for now is removing `transitive = true` and import the third-party library containing the `CustomView` to each libraries using the `baselib` which I hope could be avoid.

First I'm wondering how Jitpack was compiling the aar in order to work.
Any ideas?